# Generate rotations of a string, java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, rotation

Suppose, I have a string "big$". I need the following :

`big$
ig$b
g$bi
$big`

I also need to store these strings in an ArrayList.
Can someone please help me. I am unable to think of a solution.

This is what I have done. I am able to print it but I don't know how to store them.

```
private static void rotations(String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    char temp;
    String temp1 = null;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        System.out.println();
        for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
            System.out.print(str.charAt(j));
        for(int k=0; k<=i; k++)
            System.out.print(str.charAt(k));
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe how you get those results?

Comment: Please show your effort so far.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It looks like the characters are "rotating" left. Characters at index 1 and on shift left and the first character gets pushed to the end of the string.

Comment: @tnw No, no. Let **them** describe it.

Comment: What ideas have you had about how you could solve this? And why don't you think they will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, just instead of printing out each `char` append it to a `String` variable inside your loop, then add that variable to an `ArrayList<String>`

```
private static List<String> rotations(String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    char temp;
    String temp1 = null;

    List<String> retval = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
            sb.append(str.charAt(j));
        for(int k=0; k<=i; k++)
            sb.append(str.charAt(k));
        retval.add(sb.toString());
   }
   return retval;
}
```

And you can print those out in your main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    List<String> rotations = rotations("big$");
    for(String s : rotations)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: For better performance use `StringBuilder` and its `append` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    String a = "big$";
    char[] array = a.toCharArray();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        String temp = "" + array[i];
        for( int j = i+1; j < array.length + i; j++)
        {
            temp += array[j%(array.length)];
        }
        list.add(temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple sample of ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> container = new ArrayList<String>();
container.add("A");
container.add("B");
container.add("C");

for (int i = 0; i < container.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(container.get(i)); 
}
```